# After Spring-Boot-Upgrade 2.0.4 my Rest-Queries-Response become slow

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

After the Upgrade from 1.5 to 2.0.4, I notice that my Rest-queries-response become slow, with other words and numbers before upgrade response-time were ~25ms and after that 70ms. Can someone explain why and tell if you have also the same sace after the upgrade?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you confirm with [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) that there are no other changes but the version change?

Comment: There are no other changes! now the time to get a response for a query-select(one row) is 50ms, before the upgrade was 25ms.

Comment: Really strange. Can you confirm there are no environment changes? Also could you share the performance test procedure along with the results to give more details?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please restate your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have a query "SELECT u FROM USER u WHERE u.id = 1", before the upgrade was the response-time 25ms, now after that, the Response Needs ~50ms to give me the result. I don't think, my Question is Broad like you said! :)

Comment: Have you **painstakingly** gone through the migration guide?  Here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: I followed this Migration guide. If you find the question too broad, can you ask me, then I give you answers, this can help you more to understand the probleme, because I really don't know, how I can explain more than I did. thank you!